# XPath namepsace binding is lost after building it as document

Tags: java, xml, scala, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am trying to do a Xpath query on a string with xml format. Using javax.xml library

Here is my code (this code might seems weird because I am using scala. I converted the java codes to scala code):

```
    import javax.xml.xpath._
  import org.xml.sax.InputSource
  import java.io.StringReader
  import javax.xml.parsers._
  import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource
  import java.io.StringWriter
  import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult
  import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
  import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext
  import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
  import org.w3c.dom._
  import java.util.Iterator
  import javax.xml._
  import org.apache.ws.commons.util.NamespaceContextImpl


   val sampleXML = """<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
      <soap:Body>
        <ns2:CreateTransactionResponse xmlns:ns2="http://testing.xml.ph/provisioning/1">
          <status>404</status>
          <reason>not found</reason>
        </ns2:CreateTransactionResponse>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>"""


   val inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(sampleXML))


   var personalNameSpace = new NamespaceContextImpl
   personalNameSpace.startPrefixMapping("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
   personalNameSpace.startPrefixMapping("SOAP-ENV", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
   personalNameSpace.startPrefixMapping("ns2", "http://testing.xml.ph/provisioning/1")

   var factory = XPathFactory.newInstance()
   var xpath = factory.newXPath()

   xpath.setNamespaceContext(personalNameSpace)

   //To check whether or not the namespace is properly binded in the xpath. 
   //And it is. This one returns "PREFIX : SOAP-ENV"
   println("PREFIX : " + xpath.getNamespaceContext.getPrefix("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"))


   var dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
   var docbuild = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
   var document = docbuild.parse(inputSource)


   val testExtract = xpath.evaluate("/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/soap:Body", document, XPathConstants.NODESET).asInstanceOf[NodeList]

   println(s"testExtractSize : ${testExtract.getLength}") // Returns 0

   for(index <- 0 until testExtract.getLength) {
     val node = testExtract.item(index)
     println(s"Node Text Content: ${node.getTextContent}")
     println(s"Node LocalName: ${node.getLocalName}")
     println(s"Node Prefix: ${node.getPrefix}")
   }
```

But when I don't change it into document and just use the inputSource in my xpath. It properly returns all that I need :

```
val testExtract = xpath.evaluate("/*[local-name() = 'Envelope']/soap:Body", inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET).asInstanceOf[NodeList]
```

I get the correct logs :

```
Node Text Content: 

          404
          not found


Node LocalName: Body
Node Prefix: soap
```

Why do I need to change it into a document? Because I need to reuse it. And a InputSource wont do. I need to reinitialise it again.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do

```
var dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

before doing any XSLT/XPath with DOM documents.

Comment: Thanks! So simple! and I missed it!

Comment: I know this is already out of the question. But is it possible to get the namespace prefix and value dynamically (using the string that I just set)?

Comment: There are some implementations that allow you to get the namespace bindings declared on a certain element node but in general, as XML can have declarations at various levels that override declarations on an ancestor level (e.g. `<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">...</svg></div>`) there is no general, programmatic way to get consistent bindings for XPath evaluation.